# Invalid Unicode code point found at index ### when reading from web.config

Tags: c#, vb.net, special-characters, web-config

When calling a Method for sending an email in VB.NET (C#) all works fine when I enter the function parameters in the function call. 
But when I read those parameters from the Web.Config file it shows me a lot of errors like:

- Invalid Unicode code point found at index (for all the parameters)
- System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved (IP)
- System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The address has an invalid host name: (all the emails)

I could not find a solution for those issues because the parameters were the same.

Comment: You should edit your post to have just a question.   Then you can answer your own post with the correct answer and mark it so.  It is more helpful to readers.   BTW:  Instead of retyping the config sections manually, you could have pasted it into NotePad and then saved it with the correct file name (and proper encoding).

Comment: Now... the solution...
After some hours of problems I realise that there was a problem with special characters stored in the web.config file.

Those values like a simple email or IP were copyed from other applications (in this case from SKYPE) with a simple copy/paste operation. When we look to them, they appear to be the same, but they were stored in a special manner.

So the solution was to erase int the web.config file the entry key and type it again manually. With such approach that  were no strange/special characters in emails, descriptions, IPs or other stuff in the web.config file.

Comment: If you resolved the problem yourself, consider sharing your knowledge. Please post your solution as an answer and accept it, when you can (there is two-day delay during which you cannot accept).

Comment: The solution is presented in the post before. Just erase the entries in the web.config and retype them to ensure that no invisible or strange characters remain,